# Playframework 2.X and Date format within scala template

Tags: templates, date, playframework

How do you display a Date object to your desired pattern in a Playframework 2.X template ?

```
public class Job {
  public Date date
}
```

When i display @job.date in the scala template, i have the following displayed:

```
Tue Nov 19 12:49:46 WST 2013
```

**Expected is:**

```
19 Nov
```

**Important :**  date object is set using new Date(). I don't want to change the pattern when setting the date object, i only want to display my date with the pattern of my choice in the view. Is it possible ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In scala template:

```
@job.date.format("dd MMM")
```

Comment: Why this works within template but failed in scala file with error `value format is not a member of java.util.Date`